# What's the difference between using "both.. and" vs using just "and?"

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between using "both... and" and "and"?

For example in this sentence, "Its restriction comes as both a culture shock and a challenge." how does the meaning of the sentence change if you take away the both and make it "Its restriction comes as a culture shock and a challenge."?

Comment: Have you checked "both ... and" in any dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

> **CoGEL § 13.35** *Both … and* emphasizes the ADDITIVE meaning of *and*. It separates the conjoins and puts them on the same footing, thereby dissociating the
> conjoins from the *consequential* or *sequent* relation that might
> otherwise be implied. Contrast:
>
> • David loves Joan and (therefore) wants to marry her.
> • David both loves Joan and wants to marry her.
>
> *Both . . . and* also singles out the segregatory meaning of *and*
> rather than the combinatory use. Note the difference between:
> • David and Joan got divorced. [ie 'from each other']
> • Both David and Joan got divorced. ['so now they can get married']
>
> At first sight, *both … and* appears to stand in the same relationship to and
> as *either … or* does to *or*. But in fact, *both … and* is not admissible where the
> conjoins are full finite clauses. There must be some kind of ellipsis. Hence,
> while we can have:
>
> • Mary washed the dishes and Peter dried them.
> we cannot have:
>
> • *Both Mary washed the dishes and Peter dried them.
>
> On the other hand, *both* can be inserted if the conjoins are predicates or
> predications :
>
> • Mary both washed the dishes and dried them.
> • This new machine will both accelerate the copying process and improve
> the quality of reproduction.
> or if the conjoins are phrases:
> • *Both* Mary *and* Peter washed the dishes.
> • The regulations are *both* very precise *and* very detailed.

- "Its restriction comes as both a culture shock and challenge."

The meaning is the normal additive meaning, which is emphasized.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say using "both ... and ..." stresses that both conjoined terms are strictly of equal 'weight' or 'value' in the sentence. For instance, in the example you gave:

- "Its restriction comes as a culture shock **and** challenge."
- "Its restriction comes as **both** a culture shock **and** challenge."

In the sentence using "both ... and ...", the reader gets the impression that 'culture shock' and 'challenge' are of equal importance- it is just as much a shock as it is a challenge and you cannot remove one from the other. While the sentence using just "... and ..." *does* put the conjoined terms on an similar 'level', the emphasis that the two are linked is much weaker when compared to the sentence with "both ...  and ...".

Comment: You have misquoted the OP.  Both your bullet points should end with "and **a** challenge".  I don't know if that's why you've been downvoted - but your answer doesn't seem to add anything to that from LPH.